# Why does Grails not follow a more "Maven3" style convention

Tags: grails

I have recently switched back from using a Spring MVC/Gradle/Groovy project back to a traditional Grails project. I have been noticing the file location conventions seem, intuitively, a little less organized. For example, having Groovy src files outside of src/main/groovy (exp. Controller filter), or having the src files themselves in src/java instead of src/main/java.

Now I know all of these things can be configured, but why don't they conform closer to the Maven3 structure?

Answer (score 0):

Considering Maven 3 wasn't released until 2010 and Grails was around prior to that I don't see how they could have. The only "reason" Grails follows a different convention is because that's what the developers decided was the most logical structure for Grails. In a lot of cases it was to eliminate cruft (e.g. the /main/ in your example) or to place things more logically based on what they are.

Comment: what is your definition of cruft

Comment: Something that is there to serve a purpose other than addressing the primary problem attempting to be solved. That's my personal definition of cruft.